# Add yes/no to objshell.popup in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Below is my attempt at adding yes/no options to my objshell.popup, getting a type mismatch error, probably doing something wrong...

got it from this website: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1170490&seqNum=5

```
  Public Sub ShowTable()

Dim myData
Dim myStr As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim myRange As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim nsecond As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet


Call reviewME

UserForm1.Show

Set ws = Worksheets("New Lookups")
lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 262).End(xlUp).Row
Set myRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 262), ws.Cells(lastrow, 262))

myData = myRange.Value

For x = 1 To UBound(myData, 1)
    myStr = myStr & myData(x, 1) & vbTab & vbCrLf
Next x

'myStr = myStr & vbNewLine & "Proceed with change requests?"


inttype = vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton2

Set objshell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strtitle = "Review your entries"
nsecond = 1
intresult = objshell.popup(myStr, nsecond, strtitle, inttype)

Select Case intresult
    Case vbYes
        MsgBox "hi"
    Case vbNo
        MsgBox "no"
End Select
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the signature for the Popup method is actually:

```
WshShell.Popup(strText, [nSecondsToWait], [strTitle], [intType])
```

and you are forgetting the `nSecondsToWait` parameter.

`nSecondsToWait` may be an optional param (as indicated by the brackets around the param name) but if you aren't going to include it then you need to leave an empty slot for it:

```
intresult = objshell.popup(myStr, , strtitle, inttype)
```

The type mismatch error is because the second param should be an integer (`nSecondsToWait`) but you are giving it a string (`"Review your entries"`).

Comment: Thanks Patrick, this did the trick. However, now the popup doesn't display the text I want it to display. I've amended my code to show how mystr is created. The weird thing is if I just use `objshell.popup mystr` the popup works fine, it's when I add in the rest of the code(str title, inttype) that causes this error